# Output on a newline

Tags: java

Write a statement that prints the following on a single output line. End with a newline.
3 2 1 Go!
Note: Whitespace (blank spaces / blank lines) matters; make sure your whitespace exactly matches the expected output.

java homework

```
public class OutputExample {
   public static void main(String [] args) {

      System.out.print(321);
      System.out.print(\n + "Go");
      System.out.print("!");

      return;
   }
}
```

Output is nearly correct; but whitespace differs. See highlights below. 
Special character legend

> Your output
>   321Go!
>   Expected output
>   3 2 1 Go!

Comment: `System.out.println ("3 2 1 Go!");` - maybe I am missing the requiremnts?

Comment: @ScaryWombat If I had to guess, the next problem is going to have pauses between the numbers.

Comment: Yes, whitespace differs, because: 'System.out.print(321);' print out number 321. You want to print out string of characters including your whitespaces. You need to mark it as string. 'System.out.print("3 2 1");'

Comment: It would be real interesting if that was the output you got considering the `System.out.print(\n + "Go");` line shouldn't even compile. The **\n** (newLine) needs to be in double or single quotes.

Answer (score 0):

The problem is that you are trying to print an Integer when you write

`System.out.print(321);`

Solution:

`System.out.print("3 2 1 ");`

`System.out.print("Go!");`

Good luck!